# Flutter: How to deal with the different convention of naming between Flutter and API + MongoDB and mis-match in names?

Tags: flutter

I've been dealing with my personal project involving Flutter and MongoDB + APIs. Looks like when there is a space in words, APIs tend to use `_`. Like `picture_url`. When I am trying to create a `Model` in Flutter. I get this `Name non-constant identifiers using lowerCamelCase.dart(non_constant_identifier_names)` message. And, many use `String prictureUrl` format.

On Flutter website, it has `json_serialization` example https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/json. And, it has words without space. However, if my apis sending `picture_url` and the model on Flutter is set to `pictureUrl`, how can I convert this by using the model?

Or, how do people in the field deals with this? Do they set the names the same ways on backend and frontend?

---- edit

```
@JsonSerializable()
class User {
  User(this.profileUrl, this.email);

  String profileUrl;
  String email;

  factory User.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$UserFromJson(json);

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$UserToJson(this);
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In addition to [Rohan's answer,](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68262496/9779791) if you want to set it for whole project, you can do it in `build.yaml`.

```
targets:
  $default:
    sources:
      exclude:
        - 'example/**'
    builders:
      json_serializable:
        options:
          explicit_to_json: true 
          // this one below
          field_rename: snake
```

[json_serializable doc.](https://pub.dev/packages/json_serializable#build-configuration)

Comment: This solve everything.

Answer (score 20):

You have two options

1. Set `@JsonSerializable.fieldRename`
2. Add a `@JsonKey` annotation to a field and set properties there.

For Example

```dart
@JsonSerializable(fieldRename:FieldRename.snake)
class User {
...
}
```

```dart
class User {
    ...
    @JsonKey(name:'picture_url')
    String pictureUrl;
    ...
}
```

Additional Reading:

- [Example Package in JsonSerializeable](https://github.com/google/json_serializable.dart/tree/master/example)
- [json_annotation library](https://pub.dev/documentation/json_annotation/latest/json_annotation/json_annotation-library.html)

Comment: Thank you so much. I saw people were using `json_annotation` package and didn't really knew why they were using. However, I just read the doc but still confused. I added the example of the class. How can I apply `@JsonSerializable(fieldRename:FieldRename.snake)` in that case? Sorry for the unconvinced and thank you for your answer mate.

Comment: json_annotation provides annotation classes to use with json_serializable, in other words json_annotation is a dependency of json_serializable

Comment: What is the issue you're facing?

Comment: sovled! I just saw your edited version. I just needed the example. Cheers buddy.